# Taking file name from list and opening it?

Tags: python

I have list similar to this:

```
m=[['qw','wew','23','C:/xyz/s.wav'],['qw','wew','23','C:/xyz/s2.wav'],['qw','wew','23','C:/xyz/s1.wav']]
```

Now I want to these files

```
win=wave.open(m[0][3],'rb')
```

It is giving error how can I use this in this way...
I want to take the files name from the list

Please suggest???

Comment: looks to me like it should work, could you post the error?

Comment: in the answer you said, it is working now? what did you change? either close the question or update it.

Comment: sorry i dunno how to close,where is the option
its the same code!!
i made a minor mistake not with the code!!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
m = [['qw','wew','23','C:/xyz/s.wav'],['qw','wew','23','C:/xyz/s2.wav'],['qw','wew','23','C:/xyz/s1.wav']]
fname = m[0][3]
print 'fname is', repr(fname)
win = wave.open(fname, 'rb')
```

and show us (using copy/paste into an edit of your question) everything that is printed, especially
(1) the result of `print 'fname is', repr(fname)`
(2) the **ERROR MESSAGE**

Comment: oh thanks its working now..fine

one more i just want to know how to convert str(x) into float type

Comment: @kaushik: (1) thanks for what??? what was the problem? what did you do to fix it?(2) if you really can't extrapolate from the int(x) answer to another of your questions, then ask a SEPARATE question.